# AppIntentRecommendation doesn't list the options on watchOS for configurable widget

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, watchos, widgetkit

This is how I define my configurable widget:

```
struct WidgetGoals: Widget {
    let kind: String = "WidgetGoals"
    var families: [WidgetFamily] {
        [.accessoryCorner, .accessoryInline, .accessoryCircular, .accessoryRectangular]
    }
    
    var body: some WidgetConfiguration {
        AppIntentConfiguration(
            kind: kind,
            intent: WidgetGoalsConfiguration.self,
            provider: GoalsTimeline(), content: { entry in
                WidgetGoalsView(entry: entry)
            })
            .configurationDisplayName("goals".localized)
            .description("")
            .supportedFamilies(families)
            .contentMarginsDisabled()
    }
}
```

and this is my timeline provider:

```
@available(iOS 17, watchOS 10.0, *)
struct GoalsTimeline: AppIntentTimelineProvider {
    typealias Intent = WidgetGoalsConfiguration
    typealias Entry = GoalsEntry
    func placeholder(in context: Context) -> GoalsEntry {
        GoalsEntry(date: Date(), info: GoalInfo(goalType: .currentMonth), size: context.displaySize)
    }
    
    func snapshot(for configuration: WidgetGoalsConfiguration, in context: Context) async -> GoalsEntry {
        GoalsEntry(date: Date(), info: configuration.goal.info, size: context.displaySize)
    }
    
    func recommendations() -> [AppIntentRecommendation<WidgetGoalsConfiguration>] {
        let month = WidgetGoalsConfiguration()
        month.goal = WidgetGoal(id: "month", info: GoalInfo(goalType: .currentMonth))
        let year = WidgetGoalsConfiguration()
        year.goal = WidgetGoal(id: "year", info: GoalInfo(goalType: .currentAnnualPlan))
        return [
            AppIntentRecommendation(intent: month, description: Text("month")),
            AppIntentRecommendation(intent: year, description: Text("yesr"))
        ]
    }
    
    func timeline(for configuration: WidgetGoalsConfiguration, in context: Context) async -> Timeline<GoalsEntry> {
        let entry = GoalsEntry(date: Date(), info: configuration.goal.info, size: context.displaySize)
        let refreshDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .minute, value: 1, to: Date())!
        return Timeline(entries: [entry], policy: .after(refreshDate))
    }
}

@available(iOS 17, watchOS 10.0, *)
struct WidgetGoalsConfiguration: WidgetConfigurationIntent {
    static var title: LocalizedStringResource = "Hejka A"
    static var description: IntentDescription = IntentDescription("Widget desc")
    @Parameter(title: "goal")
    var goal: WidgetGoal
}

@available(iOS 17, watchOS 10.0, *)
struct WidgetGoal: AppEntity {
    var id: String
    var info: GoalInfo
    
    static var typeDisplayRepresentation: TypeDisplayRepresentation = "Goal"
    
    var displayRepresentation: DisplayRepresentation {
        DisplayRepresentation(title: "\(info.title)")
    }
    
    static var defaultQuery = WidgetGoalsQuery()
    
    static var all: [WidgetGoal] {
        [
            WidgetGoal(id: "month", info: GoalInfo(goalType: .currentMonth)),
            WidgetGoal(id: "year", info: GoalInfo(goalType: .currentAnnualPlan))
        ]
    }
}

@available(iOS 17, watchOS 10.0, *)
struct WidgetGoalsQuery: EntityQuery {
    func entities(for identifiers: [WidgetGoal.ID]) async throws -> [WidgetGoal] {
        WidgetGoal.all
    }
    
    func suggestedEntities() async throws -> [WidgetGoal] {
        WidgetGoal.all
    }
    
    func defaultResult() async -> WidgetGoal? {
        WidgetGoal.all.first
    }
}
```

And the results is that there is no my widget recommendations on the list when I am trying to add it to the watch face. Why? It works perfectly on iOS lock screen...